# Validar rango de fechas en php o jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

¿Como puedo condicionar en PHP 5 (o jquery) si estoy dentro de un rango de fechas?
Por ejemplo quiero condicionar el rango de fechas
Si esta dentro del rango mandar un mensaje "Dentro de Periodo"
En caso contrario "Fuera de Periodo"

El caso es que la fecha que quiero validar es 20-12-2001 y quiero saber si esta dentro del periodo del 2016 al 2017

Ejemplo : 20-12-2001  del 20-12-2015 al 2016 "Fuera del periodo"; 
                      del 20-12-2016 al 2017 "Dentro del periodo"

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Con que formato de fecha estas trabajando? Sería útil saber si estas trabajando con un formato único de fecha, o con varios, ya que sería preciso que bajo un solo formato de fecha, en Javascript puedes realizar conversiones al Objeto `Date` y hacer comparaciones con los operadores de igualdad y desigualdad

Comment: Hola buena tarde:  Te explico, trabajo con el formato
$fi=date("26-12-2001");
$fecha_ingreso=date("d-m-Y" ,strtotime($fi));
$hoy = date("d-m-Y");
La variable $fi la extraigo de una tabla MySQL en formato YYYY-MM-DD y yo lo convierto a DD-MM-AAAA con date("d-m-Y");

Comment: Ok, en base a eso creo que la respuesta de @Error404 te puede resultar útil

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu apoyo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te voy a proponer dos posibles soluciones con PHP.

#### Cuando siempre usas el mismo formato de fecha

Si tus fechas siempre son en el formato dia-mes-año puedes utilizar la función **[`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php)** de PHP para obtener el año y realizar la condición:

```
$fecha = "20-12-2001";
$fechaDividida = explode("-", $fecha);
$anno = $fechaDividida[2];

if ($anno >= 2016 && $anno <=2017){
    echo "Está dentro del periodo";
}else{
    echo "Está fuera del periodo";
}
```

Te devolverá `Está fuera del periodo` para este caso concreto.

#### Cuando usas formatos diferentes de fecha

En este caso puedes utilizar la función **[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)** junto con la función **[`date`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)** para obtener el año y después compararlo para ver si está dentro del rango:

```
$fecha = "20-12-2001";
$anno = date('Y', strtotime($fecha));

if ($anno >= 2016 && $anno <=2017){
    echo "Está dentro del periodo";
}else{
    echo "Está fuera del periodo";
}
```

Te devolverá `Está fuera del periodo` para este caso concreto.

En este último caso podrías usar `$fecha = "2001-12-20";` y te daría el mismo resultado. Incluso `$fecha = "2001/12/20";` o `$fecha = "20/12/2001";` y el resultado sería el mismo.

Comment: Perfecto y muchas gracias. Una consulta mas. Si deseo conocer que solo el dia y mes esten dentro del periodo 2016 y 2017 ¿Como extraigo esa informacion?

Comment: @JuanPabloBustamanteLuna debes marcar como correcto tu pregunta

Comment: @JuanPabloBustamanteLuna ¿A que te refieres con conocer que solo el día y mes estén dentro del período 2016  y 2017? Realmente si el año está dentro de ese rango entonces el día y el mes seguro que están en dicho rango.

Comment: Otra opción sería usar [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-split.php) y usar una `RegExp`, con los posibles _separadores_

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Sí, pero en ese caso yo utilizaría la segunda opción para no tener que estar indicando cada uno de los separadores posibles.

Comment: @Error404 Si. Ejemplo. Supongamos que la persona que tiene la fecha 20-12-2001 deseo saber si esta dentro del rango de dia y mes entre 2016 y 2017. En teoria si esta. Es decir, el dia 20 se cumple la condicion "Dentro del rango"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la clase [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) y sacar con [`->format("Y")`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php) el año y así comprobar las fechas:

```
$fecha1 = new DateTime('20-12-2001');
$fecha1 = $fecha1->format("Y"); //=> 2001
$fecha2 = new DateTime('20-12-2016');
$fecha2 = $fecha2->format("Y"); //=> 2016

$fechaInicio = new DateTime('20-12-2015');
$fechaInicio = $fechaInicio->format("Y"); //=> 2015
$fechaFin = new DateTime('01-01-2017');
$fechaFin = $fechaFin->format("Y");  //=> 2017

// Creamos una función para comprobar las fechas si están en el rango
function comprobarFecha($fecha, $fechaInicio, $fechaFin) {

    return $fecha >= $fechaInicio && $fecha <= $fechaFin;
}

// FECHA 1: 2001
if (comprobarFecha($fecha1, $fechaInicio, $fechaFin)) {

    echo 'Esta dentro del periodo';

} else {

    echo 'Esta fuera del periodo'; // <= Resultado
}    

// FECHA 2: 2016
if (comprobarFecha($fecha2, $fechaInicio, $fechaFin)) {

    echo 'Esta dentro del periodo'; // <= Resultado

} else {

    echo 'Esta fuera del periodo';
}
```

[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/849134accc00642705d782f2fb36600704386e01)

Comment: Gracias @aldanux Tambien me fue de utilidad